# Amazon Lex not prompting for missing variables when using CodeHook Validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am building an agent in Amazon Lex with around 3 intents. All the 3 intents have a variable which has been ticked as 'required', meaning the agent has to prompt for those variables when the user query is missing it.

However when I am using a lambda function as codehook validation the , function gets triggered without prompting for the missing variable.

For example: Intent which describes call notes from a call with a specific person:

The prompt is " Specify the name of the person whose notes you want to see'

The objective of the lambda function is to print out "Call notes for the person is XYZ'

When I don't use any lambda function through codehook validation, I get a prompt for the name of the person,

but when I use codehook validation, the lambda function gets triggered and I get the reply as "Call notes for None is XYZ".

None because , there wasn't any mention of the person's name in the user query nor am I getting prompted for the person's name.

Can anybody help regarding this? I have tried all sorts of modifications in the lambda function , but shouldn't the prompt be an independent functionality from the lambda function?

I have been browsing and trying things regarding this since 2~3 days and have hit a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because **Lambda initialization and validation** happens before **Slot filling** in Amazon Lex.
You can still check that user have provided the "person" slot in DialogCodeHook i.e validation part.
Something like below code will get your work done:

```
def build_validation_result(is_valid, violated_slot, message_content):
    if message_content == None:
        return {
            'isValid': is_valid,
            'violatedSlot': violated_slot
        }
    return {
        'isValid': is_valid,
        'violatedSlot': violated_slot,
        'message': {'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': message_content}
    }


def validate_person(person):
    # apply validations here
    if person is None:
        return build_validation_result(False, 'person', 'Please enter the person name')
    return build_validation_result(True, None, None)


def get_notes(intent_request):
    source = intent_request['invocationSource']
    output_session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
    slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
    person = slots['person']
    if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
        # check existence of "person" slot
        validation_result = validate_person(person)
        if not validation_result['isValid']:
            slots[ticket_validation_result['violatedSlot']] = None
            return elicit_slot(
                output_session_attributes,
                intent_request['currentIntent']['name'],
                slots,
                validation_result['violatedSlot'],
                validation_result['message']
            )
        return delegate(output_session_attributes, slots)
```

If the "person" slot is empty, user will be prompted the error message. This way you don't need to tick on "Required" on the slot.
This was the only workaround I could think of when I faced this problem while using DialogCodeHook.
Hope it helps.